# I stopped eating sehri 3:40 (twilight time), then I found out twilight time is 3:28. Is my fast still valid?

Tags: sunni, ramadan, sawm

After having read [here](http://muslimvilla.smfforfree.com/index.php?topic=880.0;wap2) and according to the Holy Quran:

> until the white thread (light) of dawn appears to you distinct from the black thread (darkness of night) [[al-Baqarah 2:187]](http://quran.com/2/187)

I was under the impression that the actual time to take sehri is longer than the Fajr time set in calendar. The Fajr time for my city is `3:28` while sunrise is `05:36`. I woke up late (3:40) for my sehri and since I had to also take my medication, I started eating and drinking till 3:58 but just now reading more about it, I realized that this "white thread" described in the Holy Quran is actually twilight not the actual sunrise. I checked it's timing for my city [here](http://24timezones.com/current_time/italy_perugia_clock.php) and it is 3:28. So my question is, was my fast valid? and What should I do if it was not?

Comment: Your fast is not invalidated if: you eat out of forgetfulness; or you mistakenly assume that your fast is broken and you eat after that; or any genuine mistake in understanding and then assuming that your fast is broken. Please continue with your fast. And don't make the same mistake again. HTH. :)

Comment: In this case, the white thread did not appear distinct to you. So could you really say that your fast was invalidated? :)

Comment: @Muz I was under the assumption that the white thread referred to the time before sun rise, only to find out it actually referred to twilight time.

Comment: Its still dark at twilight :) Muz is right. You should go camping one night far from the city and hopefully on a clear night. Wake up just enough at twilight and watch the sky go through the changes. The only people who can see twilight are in the ocean and I think this is why it is called nautical dawn too.

Answer (score 1):

From the view point of most of [Ulamas](http://talabehpasokhgoo.parsiblog.com/Posts/408/), your fast was broken, but as it wasn't intentional, you shouldn't pay Kafarah(compensation). But you have to take Qaza fast of that day.
From this [link](http://tarikh-ahkam-eslam.blogfa.com/post-3.aspx), this Hukm is an order of Sunnah (Imam Shafei) too. Sorry, if it is in Persian not English.

Comment: Is this only from scholars of the Shiite Jurisprudence or is the same from Sunnites?

Answer (score -2):

Assalamualaikum,

your fast has broken, you will have to make Qadha for it(repay it) after Ramadhaan, and Allah knows Best